# How can i see the whole data in R shiny if the data is huge(i.e 2gb)

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I  am loading the data in the shiny server.Data is a CSV file of around 2 GB .Its not showing the whole data or its taking to long to load but the head option is working .
This is the code which i have already tried, This coe is working for small files.

```
enter code here

ui <- fluidPage(

  #App title ---- 
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

      # Input: Select separator ----
      radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                   choices = c(Comma = ",",
                               Semicolon = ";",
                               Tab = "\t"),
                   selected = ","),

      # Input: Select quotes ----
      radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                   choices = c(None = "",
                               "Double Quote" = '"',
                               "Single Quote" = "'"),
                   selected = '"'),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
      radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                   choices = c(Head = "head",
                               All = "all"),
                   selected = "head")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("contents"),
      tableOutput("df")


    )

  )
)

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$contents <- renderTable({

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.

    req(input$file1)

    df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                   header = input$header,
                   sep = input$sep,
                   quote = input$quote)

    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }

  })
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=10000*1024^2)
  df <- renderTable(df)

}
# Run the app ----enter code here
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

i am expecting whole dataframe in "all" option, but its not working for lkarge data frames.

Comment: Have you tried with `DT` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

    #App title ---- 
    titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
    sidebarLayout(

        # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
        sidebarPanel(

            # Input: Select a file ----
            fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                      multiple = TRUE,
                      accept = c("text/csv",
                                 "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                 ".csv")),

            # Horizontal line ----
            tags$hr(),

            # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
            checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

            # Input: Select separator ----
            radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                         choices = c(Comma = ",",
                                     Semicolon = ";",
                                     Tab = "\t"),
                         selected = ","),

            # Input: Select quotes ----
            radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                         choices = c(None = "",
                                     "Double Quote" = '"',
                                     "Single Quote" = "'"),
                         selected = '"'),

            # Horizontal line ----
            tags$hr(),

            # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
            radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                         choices = c(Head = "head",
                                     All = "all"),
                         selected = "head")

        ),

        # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
        mainPanel(

            # Output: Data file ----
            dataTableOutput("contents")


        )

    )
)

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$contents <- renderDataTable ({

        # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
        # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
        # or all rows if selected, will be shown.

        req(input$file1)

        df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                       header = input$header,
                       sep = input$sep,
                       quote = input$quote)

        if(input$disp == "head") {
            df <- head(df)
        } else {}
        df
    })


}
# Run the app ----enter code here
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Use the DT library, "all" works, but might take a lot of time to render. I also modified your code, since there were some errors/ bad practice like `df <- renderTable(df)` which you anyway do not need here.

Comment: it is uploading fast , but its taking a lot of time to view the data because my is around 2GB. i have introduced a download button so that i can also download the file . But i am not able to download until it doesn't load the data. Is there any way to upload the file in background without viewing it ? so that i can perform my pre processing and download.

Comment: Take a look at async, I did not use it yet so I don´t know if it works. Normally R is "single threaded", which means you can only do one operation at a time. But this would be another question. Stackoverflow is not meant to used like this.